# CFeclipse on Eclipse 3.7 hangs on 10016kb

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, cfeclipse

I am trying to install CFeclipse on Eclipse 3.7. Only possible without the docshare option, but I don't think i really need that. But still, i get a problem. My install hangs when 10016kb of the file is downloaded. Then nothing happens anymore. Is CFeclipse still available or is it still maintained? Is there any other free Coldfusion editor for Eclipse available?

Comment: Yes, it is developed and maintained! I guess 3.7 it is not officially supported yet. But it works perfectly with 3.6, so if this is not critical for you -- give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use ColdFusion Builder 2, when the trial expires it turns into the express edition.

http://cfdocyard.blogspot.com/2011/05/coldfusion-builder-express-edition-free.html

But as mentioned above, I guess where 3.7 isn't released it's not yet supported, you could join the mailing lists to ask to the guys who will be able to respond directly.

http://cfeclipse.org/index.cfm/help/

Answer (score 1):

Some users have reported problems downloading the plugin.  It's a very intermittent problem and we haven't been able to track it down to a cause yet.  Are you behind a firewall or using a proxy?

If you run into this problem every time, could you please post to the user group so we can try to track down the problem?  Thanks!

Comment: I just tried to install CFE 1.4.5 on Eclipse 3.7 and it worked fine.

Comment: There's several other editors for CFML, BTW.  Besides the aforementioned CFBuilder, there's a TextMate bundle, an Idea plugin, and others.

Comment: We have to use Eclipse, because we want to work with the Mercurial Plugin as well. Since Adobe Coldfusion Builder did work flawlessly, I just came to the idea to copy the 'jre' folder to my own Eclipse 3.7 folder. Now all works!

Seems that it's the java runtime environment version is the issue here. Thought I read that somewhere, but not as clearly explained as I wanted it to be. Like, which version is likely to work with Eclipse 3.7. So then my question will be directed to denny.

@denny: which version of the Java Runtime Environment do you have installed on your computer?

Comment: I checked the version of JRE in the Readmefiles and mine is now version 6. So now I am not sure if this also will work @home where I experienced these failures. So in about 8 hours from now i'll know for sure wether it helps to copy the JRE folder from Adobe Coldfusoin Builder.

Comment: CFEclipse needs at least a Java 1.5 (java 5) runtime, I believe.  1.6 (version 6)

Comment: Er-  CFEclipse needs at least a Java 1.5 (java 5) runtime, I believe.  You should be running Java 1.6 (version 6) anyways though, unless there's a specific reason not to.  

Plus, testing java 1.5 on OS X is a real pain in the ass, as it's not readily available (because it's EOL, I guess, though that's a lame excuse IMHO).  We're aiming to stay cross-platform easily buildable.